# Calling a .dll function from a html page that runs on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, dll, cross-browser, activex

I have a dll written in c++. now i need to call the functions in the dll from a html page.

I have done this by calling the dll in vbscript (Activex) so that i can run the only in IE.

Now i need to run this on Chrome as well as Firefox.

What i have to do, whether i have to write in javascript simply or need to develop any extensions for that ?

can anyone give a solution with a simple demo for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answers friends.

I got another solution. I wrote signed applets to call dll that runs from a html or any web application. It almost run on all browsers.

Comment: Ok. But applet for running need to install jre in clinet system and you must signed applet for running correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You have no chance until you create non-portable extension for all browsers.

Firefox allows you to create [XPI](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/) extension aka "addon"

Chrome has [extensions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html)

There is no cross platform solution for DLL files, however, you can try to create flash or java applet, which will interact with your DLL, it can be "portable" enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can write an NPAPI plugin for both Mozilla and Chrome.
Or you can use Firebreath plugin, but there may arise some dependency issue.