# Call A Method In Dll Using HTML5

Tags: html, browser, dll

I have a dll file and i need to call a method in the dll and return some value.

Before i have used a VB script and called it from a html file that runs only on IE.

Now i need to call the dll directly from HTML5 without using any VBScript or Javascript.

Which tag can achieve this and that can be run in almost all browsers.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a .dll function from a html page that runs on chrome and firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430619/calling-a-dll-function-from-a-html-page-that-runs-on-chrome-and-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

There is an `<embed>` Tag, but it's not for DLLs. In fact there is no tag which allows you to call DLLs at all.

So you should step away from the idea to do your processing on the client-side and just move it to the backend. Create a ASP.NET-Service if you have to use your DLL. You can even use PHP5 (using [`COM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php) functions) if it's running on a Windows server.