# Angular - how to reference client side local activex dlls without creating nodejs server

Tags: node.js, angular, activex

I have an electron 6.0.7, angular 8, nodejs 6.9.0 application. There are activex dlls on client side, not on server side, that I need to reference them from the angular app and call their functions. How can I do it without creating local nodejs server on client side ? I have seen how to do it by creating a server locally. I am looking for solution without creating the server, cause the dlls exist locally on client side.

Comment: there is a reason for browsers not to allow the execution of client side programs and/or activeX controls: it would be a security flaw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Function from DLL loaded in front-end javascript (load dll in clientside javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34791334/call-function-from-dll-loaded-in-front-end-javascript-load-dll-in-clientside-ja)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know that this is a security risk, but these activex dlls are our dlls. On angularjs we could use: require('winax'); and call the functions of the dlls. On angulr >= 2 the typescript should be compiled and we are getting an error on the line: require('winax').

Comment: how about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41220676/4604645

Comment: I will still get an error on:  require('winax'). This is for importing js file. Thanks.