# Using local installed lib in site page

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer, dll, codebase

Is it possible to use libraries (.dll, .ocx) in modern browsers that were written for the OS Windows and registered in system32 to transfer part of the logic of the site's work and calculations from the server to the power of the local machine? For example, if a web-application is being written as a private app for private user use and you need to transfer part of the system's working logic to a local user's machine to offload the application server's capacities - how can I solve that challange?

Previously, I managed to implement a similar scheme of work in IE when I used the  tag with 'codebase' parameter, but now I need to switch to modern browsers, because IE is outdated, but so far it has not been possible to find a working way to duplicate the principle used. Maybe I can somehow use libs that worked in IE in modern browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE we can use ActiveX controls. In modern browsers, Microsoft Edge supports [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality) and IE mode supports ActiveX controls, so we can still use the same way in Edge IE mode.

But in other modern browsers, they don't support ActiveX controls and there's no way to use libraries (.dll,.ocx). I think you can only develop a program for users to download and install. You can also refer to the similar threads: [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548268/need-to-call-client-side-dll-from-browser), [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430619/calling-a-dll-function-from-a-html-page-that-runs-on-chrome-and-firefox). Except some out-of-date solutions, the conclusion is we can't do this in other modern browsers.